# Bash - Create a for loop to find all values in directories

Tags: bash

I am trying to find all the files that have a value within them. The value is within another file I created.

So the file name with all the values in them is called `value.txt`.

Where I need to search for all the values there are multiple directories with `.txt` files

I am trying something like this

```
find -name "*.txt" | xargs grep value.txt
```

I want to change this so it loops through all directories and lists all the values. I need to create a for loop to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just:

```
grep -l -r -f value.txt base_directory
```

Explanation:

- `-l` - Just print the names of the files where we found a match
- `-r` - Recurse into subdirectories.
- `-f value.txt` - Read patterns from `value.txt`
- `base_directory` - Where to look for matching files.

If you want to search multiple directories that aren't hierarchically organized:

```
for dir in some_dir1 some_other_dir some_dir/in/some_dir
do
  grep -l -r -f value.txt $dir
done
```

Comment: thanks but there are over 20 directories and I need to make it loop through all and list the files where the values exist.

Comment: heh, such an elegant solution i overlooked while figuring out the correct find/exec syntax.

Comment: not great I have subdirectories as well I need it to search through.

Comment: I think you can use a combination of the find/exec with this to enumerate multiple directories

Comment: didn't know grep took -f slick as heck